# Removing close button from dialog box in Apache Trinidad

Tags: jsp, jsf, trinidad

I am using Apache Trinidad in my JSF application.
I have used the dialog framework in Trinidad to display dialog boxes.
I am looking for a way to hide the close button from the dialog boxes.
How can I achieve this?
In my managed bean method I have done this

```
return "dialog:customerSavePopUp";
```

In `faces-config.xml` I have written the navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>dialog:customerSavePopUp</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/jsp/customerSavePopUp.jsp</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

This creates the dialog boxes perfectly but I need to hide the close button from the JSP pages that is displayed as dialog boxes.
Basically, I am showing JSP pages as dialog boxes, is it possible to hide the close button from the JSP page?

Comment: I don't know if you are talking about the cross in the top right corner of your dialog window?
Do you?

Comment: yes , that is exactly what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't hide this button. But I never tried.

But you can implement a ReturnListener which will be called if someone clicks the cross.

So you might have something like this to react on a close-Button you have created:

```
public String closeButton()
{
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().returnFromDialog(null,null);
    return (null);
}
```

This would be a Listener reacting on the cross:

```
public void returned (ReturnEvent event)
{
          //Do your necassary stuff
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to know what should go inside the ReturnListener so that the dialog bx does not closes when the close button in title bar is clicked.Can you help?

Comment: @Ikdg even after trying a lot I could not figure out a way to stop the dialog box getting close when the cross button is clicked in the title bar.Is it even possible?Is there any thing that I can put inside the return listener so that the dialog box does not close when the cross button in clicked?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea and I have never tried it. My suggestion with the ReturnListener was because I thought you would have to do some operations if the user closes the dialog. Maybe the trinidad tr:popups in modal mode satisfy your needs.

Comment: Are you referring to tr:panelPopup?How can I open a panelPopup from a managedbean class(Like I opened the dialog boxes from the managed bean class itself).

Comment: This could work with some "ugly" javascript workaround.   FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   ExtendedRenderKitService erks = Service.getRenderKitService(fc, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
   erks.addScript(fc, "document.getElementById('btntestpopup').click();");                                                                                                                                   where btntestpopup is the button to open the tr:panelpopup.